# How to persist data between login sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a php/mysql setup.  My question is simple and I believe I already have the answer.  I have different users who logon to this php site, and modify settings for each user.  For example I login with user, and change the time to 9pm.  When I log off and log back in the time is set to blank again, I am using sessions by the way.  In order to have the set value every time I login I would have to store the value in the mysql database in order to retrieve it every time I login correct?

Or is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, correct. Information in sessions is gone once the session is destroyed (user logged out).

To store information persistently, use a database.
You could also write it to a file for the same effect, but I'd recommend the database approach.

Comment: Agreed. Any reason why to use database instead of file? I mean, it's much simpler, but any reason other than that?

Comment: @JCO Admittedly, this heavily depends on the specific use case; sometimes plain files *are* the way to go. But, databases are usually faster, handle concurrent access a lot better and abstract the headaches of mass-information storage away.

Answer (score 0):

Right. PHP doesn't have global app level, after session are file or DB.
A file implement [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=1825). Just in case.